# Notification Center Posting Notification with User-Info

Tags: ios, swift, notificationcenter

For my code base, I have 3 functions and 3 dispatch groups (dg)

so when the 1st function is done, dg1's notify method is called and it calls func 2, and once that is done, dg2's notify method is called and func 3 is called once that is finished dg3's notify is called, I have my data and I use it for further processing.

All the above logic is in another file

I want to pass the data is of func 3, available in dg3's notify-execute method to my vc. I employed the notification center for this method. Using the following:

```
 let imageDataDict:[String: UIImage] = ["image": image]

  // post a notification
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationName"), object: nil, userInfo: imageDataDict) 
  // `default` is now a property, not a method call

 // Register to receive notification in your class
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showSpinningWheel(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationName"), object: nil)

 // handle notification
 // For swift 4.0 and above put @objc attribute in front of function Definition  
 func showSpinningWheel(_ notification: NSNotification) {

  if let image = notification.userInfo?["image"] as? UIImage {
  // do something with your image   
  }
 }
```

However I never get the notification. How do I resolve this problem. I want to pass the data from the dispatch group elsewhere -in this case my VC.

Comment: I presume you have just shown the post and addobserver lines out of context to show what you are doing? You need to add the observer before you post a notification.

Comment: @Paulw11 I believe OP has not shown full code because it could be long and tedious, as there are many dispatch group's as they say. However I believe they are doing it correctly - in dg3 they make the dictionary and post it in user notification and in the other file AKA VC they have set it up correctly, and dont get it. I have set an example project to help them but could not get it to work as well. I dont know what could be wrong.

Comment: They haven't shown enough code nor provided information on the debugging they have tried. They should provide a [mcve]. The question talks about dispatch groups, but no code is shown for that. Have they set breakpoints to confirm that the dispatch group is being notified correctly? To confirm they are posting the notification?  Posting and receiving notifications in Swift certainly works, so there is a problem with their code, but they haven't shown enough of it.

Comment: I just put together a quick test app and I had no problem posting a notification from one object back to another.  Your code is a bit of a mish-mash of styles; You should use `Notification` not `NSNotification` in Swift - The two classes are bridged, so it will work either way, but as I said, stylistically you avoid `NS` classes in Swift where possible.  Second, in Swift you would prefer the `addObserver(forName:, object: nil, queue:, using:)` form and provide a closure rather than using the selector form.  So, again, please provide more debugging information and more code

Comment: @Paulw11 Please check this out, this is what I have done, I dont get the notification in the third dispatch group. In the first (if i do it outside of notify of dg1, else inside, i dont) I do but not inside the dispatchgroup.notify of any. I have added the code here [SAMPLE](https://github.com/shehryar01/stackOverflowSample/blob/7a40b1ad2346848d03f14f3927dc3b394cbd402d/Sample%20code%20for%20notification%20posting.txt)  . the functions you see inside the loop are alamofire ones, that just parse data from my personal server (dummy data). i have replicated what the OP has done

Comment: You definitely don't need dispatch group 1 since there is no asynchronous code  in the for loop. It doesn't look like you need the other two dispatch groups either, but maybe you have some asynchronous functions that aren't clear.  You never call `leave` on dispatch group 2 or  3 in the code shown which is perhaps why it never notifies.

Comment: You should really re-structure your code so that asynchronous functions take a completion handler and then you can use a local dispatch group and `leave` in the completion handler rather than using globals and having the code spread all over the place. You haven't shown the code but is is likely that there is a path where `leave` isn't called in dispatch group 3.

Comment: Using multiple arrays with associated values is also a "code smell". Use an array of a `struct` with the required properties; in fact you are taking the properties from whatever is in the `data` array and splitting it into multiple arrays. Don't do that. Just use the array of objects you already have. You don't need that entire `for' loop in the first function.

Comment: Also, passing a 'view` to these functions is coupling them unnecessarily to your view. These functions should `throw' or return a `Result` and then the caller can decide how to handle the error, such as showing toast

Comment: @Paulw11 There was asynchronus code and I did call the `leave` but didnt show it. My apologies, I have added them and the full class to make it clearer. `helloX()` is just a dummy function I was checking if it was posting a notification or not. Alright thankyou, I shall de-couple it and throw a result instead for the toast. However I am not sure how to do so, I need to send an ID back of the one that failed and then send a toast with that ID telling the user its offline. How can that be done?

Comment: You can associate a value with your `Error` subclass if you need some associated value. Regardless, there isn't enough code *in your question itself* to tell you where you are going wrong.  Certainly the notification code you have shown works.

Comment: You have top make sure you always `leave` the dispatch group.  For example in the `guard` in `getSIDRequest` you don't `leave`.  Have you set breakpoints to confirm that you are getting to your `notify`? You can single step through your code to see what is happening.  You should eliminate all of the globals and use closures.  You are messing with global state from multiple threads and that can lead to bugs and makes your whole code so much harder to follow

Comment: @Paulw11 I actaully go leave in `guard` of `getSIDRequest` with `self?.dg2.leave()` which is then followed by return. I have figured out why this doesnt work as intended as I was confused since the code for posting a notification was correct. I moved setting up for `notification` and `UpdatedStateBackend.shared.getDB(view: view)` to `viewWillAppear` and all notifications work as intended. Not sure why this was not working in viewDidLoad for me

Comment: How do I associate a value with the error subclass?. I have an enum called `failure: Error{ case timeout }` and I can use this if the call timesout however how do I associate a value to this?

Comment: As I said, create a subclass of `Error` - Your subclass can have whatever additional properties you like.  In your completion handler you can test to see if you have an instance of your subclass via a conditional downcast and then access those properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235778/discussion-between-paulw11-and-shehryar-ahmad-rajput).